# How to solve $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{x\sec^2 x-\tan x}{x^2+\tan^2 x}dx=\pi/4$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What could be the way to solve the following difficult integral
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{x\sec^2 x-\tan x}{x^2+\tan^2 x}dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
because nothing seems to be working I tried substitutions and integration by parts. Next, I tried the properties of definite integral. I want your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numerator of the integral can be rewritten as

$$x^2 \: \frac{d(\frac{\tan(x)}{x})}{dx}$$

Now substitute it into the integral
Now
$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{x^2 \:\:\frac{d(\frac{\tan(x)}{x})}{dx}\:\:dx}{(x^2+(\tan(x))^2)}}$$

Now we can factorise $x^2$ from the denominator and simplify to obtain
$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\:\frac{d(\frac{\tan(x)}{x})}{dx}\:\:dx}{(1+(\frac{(\tan(x))}{x})^2)}}$$

Now use substitution $$U=\left(\frac{(\tan(x))}{x}\right)$$

Finally
where $$f(x)=\arctan\left(\left(\frac{(\tan(x))}{x}\right)\right)$$
$$I=f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-f(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$